# Visual studio C# Linq bulk insert/update

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, bulkinsert

I have recently developed a C# application using Linq.
I am getting from an external database a list of profiles I need to process, some are new and some are already in the database, and need to be updated.
What I do today is go over the profile list and check each profile if such exists I update otherwise I insert - this solution is working fine.

I am sure there is a way to use bulk insert/update something like UPDATE ON DUPLICATE, this way I can save time since the files I get are huge and bulk insert/update is known to have better performance. I would like to avoid the iteration I am now using.

insertall doesn't work for already stored rows, I need the combination of both update and insert

Here is my code, Your help is highly appreciated.

```
foreach (Profile tmpProfile in profiles)
            {
                try
                {                      
                    var matchedProfile = (from c in db.ProfileEntities
                                          where c.ProfileId == tmpProfile.Id
                                          select c).SingleOrDefault();

                    if (matchedProfile == null)
                    {
                        //Insert
                        db.ProfileEntities.InsertOnSubmit(EntityMapper.ToEntity(tmpProfile));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Update
                        EntityMapper.ToEntity(ref matchedProfile, tmpProfile);                           

                    }                                               
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException sqlExec)
                {                       

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }

            db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible optimisation would be to create a list of all the items that you have from the external application, and then read all items from the database that match at once, instead of doing multiple round trips.

You can then update all of those, insert all of the ones that are left and call SubmitChanges at the end - you will then have 2 round trips to the database instead of one per profile retreived externally.

I don't know of any bulk update or insert features in Linq to SQL

Comment: It means I'll have to iterate over the list of items to determine which are located in the database and then update one by one, do you think it is better?

Comment: Hi there

The performance hit of doing one large hit on the database, and iterating over that, should be less than doing many small calls to the database.

So you should have a net optmisation.

Comment: How do I do such optimization? I am aware of the fact that bulk is preferable but is there a way to do that using LINQ? in terms of both insert and update in a bulk operation.

Comment: For the bulk read, you can use the Linq equivalent of an "In" operation in T-SQL. see the blog post at : http://hsterby.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-make-t-sql-in-query-with-linq-to.html

I haven't tested it, but it looks like it would work.

Bulk updates are not supported in Linq. It does batch all of your individual updates to the objects when you call SaveChanges, resulting in a single round trip. But that is as far as it goes.